# What is the best way of change ArrayList priority, a task can be moved from one list to the other

Tags: java, arraylist

Changing list array priorities. A task can be moved from one list to the other. The idea is that changing the priority of a low-priority task will remove it from the low-priority list and add it to the end of the high-priority list. However, changing the priority of a high-priority task will add it to the beginning of the list of low-priority tasks also 6.Promoting a task. This method will move a high priority task one up the list (the head of the list is the task at index 0). When this method is called with the first task (the one at index 0), there should be no effect (since the task can’t actually go higher up).

```
          public void changePriority(boolean important, int index) {
            
                    if (important) {
                               
                            
                            int endOfList = highPriority.size();
                            
                              highPriority.add(lowPriority.get(index));
                              lowPriority.add(0, highPriority.get(endOfList));
                              removeHighPriorityTask(endOfList);// to remove task in lowPriority
                            
                    } else {
                        
                        
                        int endOfList = highPriority.size();
                        
                        highPriority.add(endOfList, lowPriority.get(index));
                       
                        removeLowPriorityTask(index);
                        
                        // -- promote
                        promote(endOfList);
                       
                    }
            
                }
            
            /* Initialises both lists, to initially be empty. */
                public void initialiseLists() {
            
                    this.lowPriority = new ArrayList<String>();
                    this.highPriority = new ArrayList<String>();
            
                }
        
        public void promote(int index) {
        
        
                  Integer value = index;
                  value = value ++; // increment value
                  
                  highPriority.set(value, highPriority.get(index));
                 
                
            }
        /*
         * 
         *
         * @param task string to add at the end of the low Priority List
         */
        public void addTask(String task) {
    
            //lowPriority.add(task);
            //highPriority.add(task);
            int endOfList = lowPriority.size();
            lowPriority.add(endOfList, task);
    
        }
    
    public ArrayList<String> highPriority, lowPriority; // the two lists of tasks

/* Produces a string with all the tasks in both lists. */
    public String toString() {

        String taskString = "";

        for (String s : lowPriority) {
            taskString += s + "\t";
        }

        return taskString; // dummy return value (before this method is implemented)
    }

/* Main class */
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ListsManager tasks = new ListsManager();
        tasks.addTask("test 1");
        tasks.addTask("test 2");
        tasks.addTask("test 3");
        tasks.changePriority(true, 1);

        // -- print out
        System.out.print("Lists " + tasks.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using a TreeSet instead of the ArrayList and a Task Object with a priority number?

Comment: No please, the requirement is ArrayList.